# Wrong page count in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

My report is saying there are 12 of 14 pages.  There really is only 12 pages.  I am not getting any blank pages in the beginning, middle or end of my report.  I've checked all the obvious things, my body + margins are less then my page size, I've set ConsumeContainerWhitespage to True.  I just don't know what else to check.  Please help!!  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try by adding report header and put the code for calculating the pages.

```
= "Page # " & Globals!PageNumber & " of " & Globals!TotalPages & " pages."
```

Comment: I have tried both =Globals!OverallPageNumber & " " & Parameters!sOf.Value & " " & Globals!OverallTotalPages AND =Globals!PageNumber & " " & Parameters!sOf.Value & " " & Globals!TotalPages.  Still getting 12 of 14.

Comment: Did you try this on report header or footer?

Comment: Yes, this is in the report header.  The other funny thing is, the report footer prints on the last page, page 12.